# monitor memory of gce by stackdriver

Tags: memory, google-compute-engine, stackdriver

I wanna monitor memory of gcp vm, and I already install monitoring agent, step by step from [link](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/install-agent#agent-install-debian-ubuntu).

the problem is i still cant get information of memory on the stackdriver dashboard.
did i miss something?

[image: screenshot]

and when i type "sudo service stackdriver-agent status"
get the log "write_gcm: can not take infinite value"
what does it mean?
Is there a connection between those two?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the Stackdriver agent is alive, you should check if it actually generates and pushes any data.  There're basic checks you can start from:

1. Restart the agent.
2. Try another time period on the chart (1D or 1W).
3. Try a CPU metric and see whether data is shown.
4. Check system logs (journalctl, /var/log/syslog,
   /var/log/messages) for messages containing "collectd" or
   "stackdriver-agent".
5. Verify a service account used by the VM. If you use a custom service account, make sure it has a role "roles/monitoring.metricWriter". See [Access control](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/access-control).
6. Verify that data is arriving in Monitoring by manually calling the [timeseries.list](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.timeSeries/list?apix=true#try-it) method in API Explorer

Troubleshooting steps are described in details here: [Troubleshooting Agent Installation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/troubleshooting)

The error "write_gcm: can not take infinite value" could be caused by disabled swap.